# ASP .NET linq Cannot access Session from View

Tags: html, linq, view

I can' seem to properly grab a value from session within my cshtml file.

I have all the proper using statements:

startup.cs contains:

```
services.AddSession();
 app.UseSession();
```

Controller contains:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

No errors setting a value in session:

Here is my call according to my teacher which is not working for me:

```
@HttpContext.Session.GetString("test");
```

Webpage returns:

```
The name 'HttpContext' does not exist in the current context
```

There is a problem with my reference in the cshtml. I don't know if I'm looking in the wrong places but I can't seem to find anything on this on the web.

Comment: using System.Web;

Comment: yes, probably you're missing the reference